# Homeomorphisms of the cuspidal cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Are the cuspidal cubics $V(y^2-x^3)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ and $V(X^3-Y^2Z)\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$? I think I can see the homeomorphism in my mind (just "pull" from the sides of the cusp) but would like little more rigorus explanation.

Comment: For irreducible curves, things are easy. Affine irreducible curves carry the cofinite topology, so any two equipotent curves are homeomorphic (e.g. $V(y^2-x^3)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$). The homeomorphism then lifs to the projective closures.

Comment: The question is a little vague, but the motivation might have been to ask whether, over $\mathbf{C}$, these curves are homeomorphic in the _analytic_ topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking whether they are *isomorphic* to $\mathbf A^1$ and $\mathbf P^1$ respectively (which is the right question to ask in this context - the underlying topology is not so interesting, as Alex points out), then the answer is no. Indeed, the cuspidal cubic has a singularity, while $\mathbf A^1$ and $\mathbf P^1$ are smooth.

Comment: (+1) Operatively, $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is <b>not</b> normal.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Isn't the point precisely that it *isn't* normal?

Comment: Oops, I a word.

Comment: I think the question is about the analytic topology though...